# How to ftp php code including vendor folder using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: php, composer-php, bitbucket-pipelines

I have php project in bitbucket.
I am able to install composer and generate vendor folder using pipeline.
Currently, there are no unit test cases. Hence, no script added to execute test cases.
Further, I need to ftp files and vendor folder both to my server. Below is current bitbucket-pipeline.xml

```
image: php:7.2.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - cd src
          - composer install
```

Following is suggested to push files but this is supposed to push only changed files.

```
- apt-get -qq install git-ftp
- git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS/PATH_TO_WEBSITE/
```

I am blocked over:

Using "git ftp push" will only push changed file from last commit. 
How to ftp vendor folder as well? Complete folder needs to be ftp. This folder is generated while executing pipeline script. Its not checked in repository.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue. In order to deploy vendor dir as well, just remove it from .gitignore , add it to you project commit it. pipelines will catch it and deploy as normal directory.

Comment: Thanks. Thats one way but its not correct per se for us as generated/downloaded files here are not supposed to be checked in.

Comment: I see bitbucket generating vendor folder using composer as defined in pipeline.. I need someway to pick that folder and  ftp it