# How update laravel vendor folder on the website server using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: php, git, laravel, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

This is a my bitbucket-pipelines.yml and project in Laravel
i [How to ftp php code including vendor folder using bitbucket pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130876/how-to-ftp-php-code-including-vendor-folder-using-bitbucket-pipeline) this but not working, please help, thanks :)

```
image: php:7.2

pipelines:
    branches:
      dev:
        - step:
            caches:
              - composer
            script: # Modify the commands below to build repository.
              - apt-get update
              - apt-get install -y unzip
              - apt-get -qq install git
              - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
              - apt-get update
              - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
              - composer install
              - git status -uno --porcelain
              - git ftp push --user user12 --passwd abcd1234 ftp://ftp.site.com/dev.site.com/
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask]. I don't see anything that would cause `vendor/` to be pushed here, unless I misunderstand what `git ftp` does. If `vendor/` isn't tracked it won't be pushed because it doesn't exist in any commits.

Comment: vendor folder not updated on website server

Comment: What part of what you've shown above is supposed to put the `vendor/` folder on your server?

Comment: i know this is not tracked but how can i do for that

Comment: vendor folder not have in server

Comment: if you have .gitignore file please make sure remove the vendor/ folder..